# Zf2 Fatal error: Class 'BookList\Controller\BookController' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'me developing an app in zf2. when I define routes in `module.config.php` and access them in my browser, php throws error :

`Fatal error: Class 'BookList\src\BookList\Controller\BookController' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\projects\autoclick\skeleton-application\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php on line 170`

here is my module.config.php :

```
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'BookList\src\BookList\Controller\Book' => 'BookList\src\BookList\Controller\BookController'
        )
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'book' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/book[/][:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[0-9]+'
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'BookList\src\BookList\Controller\Book',
                        'action' => 'index'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'book' => __DIR__ . '/../view'
        )
    )
```

I have my `BookController` namespaced `BookList\src\BookList\Controller`

Comment: have you setup autoloader for your module?

Answer (score 2):

This should be:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'BookList\Controller\Book' => 'BookList\Controller\BookController' // <- change key and value
    )
),
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'book' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/book[/][:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id' => '[0-9]+'
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'BookList\Controller\Book', // <- change
                    'action' => 'index'
                )
            )
        )
    )
),
```

Comment: I tried it and I changed my namespace to BookList\Controller for my Controller class but it doesn't work

Comment: What error do you get now? What is the full path to your book controller?

Comment: my full class path is skeleton-application\module\BookList\src\BookList\Controller\BookController and the error is Fatal error: Class 'BookList\Controller\BookController' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\projects\autoclick\skeleton-application\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php on line 170

Comment: You also said in your question your controller was namespaced as `BookList\src\BookList\Controller`, but this should be `BookList\Controller`. If it still doesn't work, please edit your question to include the first few lines of the controller class (up to and including the `class BookController` line).

Answer (score 1):

You should not specify the path, but only the class name, e.g. remove \BookList\src\ part. The namespace also should not container the src folder

Comment: can you post a code snippet please, I don't get it complete.

Comment: see @Tim Fountain answer